# ¿Cómo convertir un data.frame en un formato horizontal a uno vertical?

Tags: r

Tengo algunos problemas para convertir mi `data.frame` de una lineal a una vertical.

```
Code Espece avreviada       2005    2006   2007    2008    2009
ST stypopodium trascend   15  22,5 19,5 2,5  23,14  45
AG  anfiroa fragilisima        2,2   12,5   15,7  11,3  12,2
```

Este ejemplo es personal, pero puede ser reproducido por el código de países que trae la base en R:

```
Code Country        1950    1951    1952    1953    1954
AFG  Afghanistan    20,249  21,352  22,532  23,557  24,555
ALB  Albania        8,097   8,986   10,058  11,123  12,246
```

Necesito que eso salga de forma vertical:
Es posible hacerlo con `reshape()` ?

Algo como: `reshape(), v.names = "Value", idvar = ¿?` Acá me enredo con el código, alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es cierto, [`reshape()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/reshape.html) es un poco confuso para usar, en general cada vez que lo necesito, tengo que volver a leer la ayuda y los ejemplos ( `?reshape`) para acordarme. Primero preparemos un ejemplo similar al que diste:

```
df <- read.table(text="Code Espece avreviada 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009
ST stypopodium trascend   15  22.5 19.5  2.5 23.14
AG  anfiroa fragilisim    2.2 12.5 15.7 11.3 12.2", header=T, strip.white = T, stringsAsFactors=F)
colnames(df) <- c('Code','Espece','avreviada','2005','2006','2007','2008','2009')

df
  Code      Espece  avreviada 2005 2006 2007 2008  2009
1   ST stypopodium   trascend 15.0 22.5 19.5  2.5 23.14
2   AG     anfiroa fragilisim  2.2 12.5 15.7 11.3 12.20
>
```

Claramente está en un formato "ancho" y lo que buscas es pasarlo al formato "largo", entiendo que lo que hay que expandir son los valores de los años. La forma más básica de hacerlo es la siguiente:

```
reshape(data=df, 
        direction="long", 
        varying=list(4:8), 
        times=names(df)[4:8], 
        timevar="Year", 
        v.names="Valor")
```

Tres parámetros mínimos son suficientes en este caso:

- `data`: Es el `data.frame` a ajustar
- `direction`: `long` o `wide`
- `varying` : Independientemente de lo que diga la ayuda, es una lista con los nombres o lo índices de las columnas que transformaremos de su distribución horizontal a vertical, en nuestro ejemplo son las columnas `2005`, `2006`, `2007`, `2008`, `2009`, se pueden indicar por el número: `list(4:8)` o por nombre `list(names(df)[4:8])`.

Parámetros opcionales:

- `times`: Para indicar que valores vamos a trasladar, si no indicamos nada será un índice, haciendo `times=names(df)[4:8]`trasladamos directamente el nombre de la columna.
- `timevar`, para indicar el nombre de la columna dónde se trasladarán el nombre de cada año.
- `v.names`, para indicar el nombre de la columna dónde se trasladarán los valores

La salida:

```
       Code      Espece  avreviada Year Valor id
1.2005   ST stypopodium   trascend 2005 15.00  1
2.2005   AG     anfiroa fragilisim 2005  2.20  2
1.2006   ST stypopodium   trascend 2006 22.50  1
2.2006   AG     anfiroa fragilisim 2006 12.50  2
1.2007   ST stypopodium   trascend 2007 19.50  1
2.2007   AG     anfiroa fragilisim 2007 15.70  2
1.2008   ST stypopodium   trascend 2008  2.50  1
2.2008   AG     anfiroa fragilisim 2008 11.30  2
1.2009   ST stypopodium   trascend 2009 23.14  1
2.2009   AG     anfiroa fragilisim 2009 12.20  2
```

Los `rowname` y la columna `id` son datos colaterales que genera la función.